# How can I link another view controller's sub view into current xib which is using auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib, viewcontroller, subview

My condition:
1. I have an xib which is using auto layout (VC1) 
2. There are some UI controls in this xib (VC1) 
3. I have another view controller (VC2) which is using xib with auto layout as well
4. I want to re-use VC2 in VC1

How can I configure xib in VC1 to re-use VC2's view ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Xibs are really bad if you want to reuse UI.

Longer answer: I would add the view of VC2 in code to VC1 and add also in code the layout constraints you need.

Comment: Can I set a view (view2) in VC2's xib with constraints, then manually create VC1 in VC2 by codes, add VC1's view (view1) as sub view of VC1, assign view1 with view2's constraints ?